# Output fps in someone else's game

Tags: c++, directx, hook, directx-11

Good afternoon everyone. I want to make a conclusion fps in someone else's game. I'm getting into the game process, in this case the DirectX 11 application is a demo from Unity.
I start the demo, put the window mode 800x600. Further I load there my dll. Everything is fine, the frame counter is drawn.
If you switch to full-screen mode (Alt + Enter), the counter disappears,
that is not drawn on the screen. If we go back, then in the windowed mode it is displayed again normally.
If you run the demo immediately in full-screen mode at a resolution equal to the screen resolution (for me it is 1440 by 900), then the counter
is displayed normally.

What could be the reason? I have the impression that there are two textures,
in which the rendering takes place, and depending on the resolution
is one of them displayed?
Here's the SwapChain data after the Present () hook:

```
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc = {};
hr = swap->GetDesc(&swapChainDesc);

swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = 800
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = 600
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 0 
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1 
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM (28)
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED (0)
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED (0)

swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 2
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0 

swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = 48
swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1
swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = 0x000000000006087c {unused=71304240 }
swapChainDesc.Windowed = 1
swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD (0)
swapChainDesc.Flags = 2
```

I suspect that this is affected by the parameter: swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 2
Also what then to do? How to display text?
Is this Multi-Sample Anti-Aliasing affecting it or not?

In the window (800x600):

[image]

In full screen mode (800x600):

[image]

In full screen mode (1440x900, screen resolution):

[image]

Comment: I think you should re-apply your Present(1) hook when the full-screen mode toggles.

Comment: I tried it. It did not help.

Comment: Do you hook both Present and Present1? What do you use for hooking? A third-party lib or your own code? I have been successful using minhook for instance.